# Missing files in Django admin dashboard

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm a newbie in Django and I have this problem.
When I enter to my admin dashboard, CSS and JS files aren't shown. When I follow the URL, it appears

> 404 Not Found

I'm using Nginx + Gunicorn.

This is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
server_name MYPROJECT.COM;

access_log off;

location /static {
    alias /opt/myenv/myenv/MYPROJECT/static/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}
```

Also this is settings.py static configuration:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

My css admin files are stored in`/opt/myenv/myenv/MYPROJECT/static/admin`
, but also in `/opt/myenv/myenv/static/admin`

I've uploaded the files in both directories and run `collectstatic`
Can anyone help me?
Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

We had issues getting collectstatic working with admin in an older version of Django, and fixed it in our nginx config by doing something like

```
location /static {
    root /path/project;
}
location /static/admin {
    root /path/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin;
}
```

Comment: I've added location /static/admin in this way but still doesn't work

Comment: In your position now, I'd use the browser tools to see what URLs the app is trying to fetch, then I'd match those up against nginx logs.